# Using IEx.pry raise compile error

Tags: elixir

Sorry if this is a simple question but I am very new to elixir, and I don't have a erlang background.

I am trying to run the following code, but It gives a error.

~ cat foo.ex

```
defmodule Math do

  def add(a, b) do
    a + b
    IEx.pry
  end

end

IO.puts(Math.add(1, 2))
```

~ elixir foo.ex

```
** (CompileError) foo.ex:5: tried to invoke macro IEx.pry/0 but module was not required. Required: Integer, Kernel, Kernel.Typespec, Record
    src/elixir_dispatch.erl:209: :elixir_dispatch.expand_macro_fun/7
    src/elixir_dispatch.erl:197: :elixir_dispatch.expand_require/6
    src/elixir_dispatch.erl:116: :elixir_dispatch.dispatch_require/6
    lists.erl:1329: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    lists.erl:1330: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    src/elixir_translator.erl:59: :elixir_translator.translate_each/2
    lists.erl:1329: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

I don't see any reference for that modules: Integer, Kernel, Kernel.Typespec, Record [in the docs](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/d50cd8a681991ee108a7694009235f960e294df4/lib/iex/lib/iex.ex#L250). So I don't know how to proceed.

I am using the `Elixir 0.11.1-dev` version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly require the IEx module before using it:

```
require IEx
IEx.pry
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: What's the best way to have IEx be available in all test files? Similar to requiring commonly used modules in Rails spec_helper